# PID of processes in docker container when run commands via &&

Tags: linux, docker

I wrote a DOCKERFILE and use `CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "script1.sh && script2.sh"` to start container.

After running a container, I found that the process with PID 1 is a process with CMD column bash, and script2.sh is its child process.

```
F S   UID   PID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  TTY          TIME CMD            
4 S     0     1     0  0  80   0 -  4491 wait   ?        00:00:00 bash           
0 S     0     8     1  0  80   0 -  4494 wait   ?        00:00:00 script2
0 S     0    10     8 99  80   0 - 1632452 futex_ ?      00:01:05 java           
4 S     0    64     0  0  80   0 -  4545 wait   ?        00:00:00 bash           
0 R     0    79    64  0  80   0 -  1785 -      ?        00:00:00 ps
```

If I use `CMD [ "/bin/bash", "-c", "script2.sh" ]`, the process with PID 1 is script2.sh.

Could someone help explain what would happen in the first case?

Comment: can you post some output logs

Answer (score 0):

In both cases, `bash` starts out as PID 1.

For the first example, `bash` is going to run the command `"script1.sh && script2.sh"`, first invoking a subshell to execute `script1.sh`, then another subshell to execute `script2.sh` *if* `script1.sh` and its subshell exited without errors. The full output (i.e. from `ps -ef`) will show the command as `/bin/bash -c "script1.sh && script2.sh"`.

For the second example, `bash` is running a single command, and essentially `exec`s that command. No subshell is needed, and `script2.sh` can replace and becomes PID 1.